# The Closure.delegate does not work with an object containing a methodMissing method?

Tags: groovy

My test code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

class Inner {
    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        println "inner:${name}"
    }
}

def foo = {
    bar()
}

foo.delegate = new Inner()
foo.call()
```

It gives result:

```
inner:bar
```

If I add another methodMissing method, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

class Inner {
    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        println "inner:${name}"
    }
}

// This method is added
def methodMissing(String name, args) {
    println "outer:${name}"
}

def foo = {
    bar()
}

foo.delegate = new Inner()
foo.call()
```

It gives result:

```
outer:bar
```

Why? I set the delegate to the closure 'foo'. Why isn't Inner. methodMissing   called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this doc](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_delegation_strategy_2), I believe you'll want to change the resolution strategy. I have added a `foo2` and some asserts to illustrate the contrast in behaviour:

```
class Inner {
    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        println "inner:${name}"
        return "inner:${name}"
    }
}

def methodMissing(String name, args) {
    println "outer:${name}"
    return "outer:${name}"
}

def foo = { bar() }

foo.delegate = new Inner()
assert "outer:bar" == foo.call()

def foo2 = { bar() }

foo2.delegate = new Inner()
foo2.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
assert "inner:bar" == foo2.call()
```